# Determine the name of a file to download

Tags: delphi, http, wininet

I need to download a file from a url which has format similar to `http://server.com/settings/files/1` when I paste this url in a web-browser this can determine the name of the file to download in this case `scheme_563.txt`, my question is how I can retrieve the name of the file (which obviously is not included in the url) to download  using the wininet functions? currently i am using the [`HttpQueryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with multiples values like HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LOCATION,HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION, etc. but without luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields, the [Content-Disposition header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) includes this information

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fname.ext
```

Maybe this optional header is available in the response to a HTTP GET or HEAD request in this case.

Note that the filename may be encoded - see [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) for a discussion